# How to increase resolution on highchart when rendering PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pdf-generation, jspdf

Basically I want to know,What is the best way render Highchart's charts on PDF?. In my case I use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) with [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to render pdf. But its chart resoution is very low on generated PDF.How I improve resolution on chart

Following code section for creating **canvas** element from **svg**. There is method to get **svg** from **Highchart**

```
(function (H) {
        H.Chart.prototype.createCanvas = function (divId) {
            var svg = this.getSVG(),
                    width = parseInt(svg.match(/width="([0-9]+)"/)[1]),
                    height = parseInt(svg.match(/height="([0-9]+)"/)[1]),
                    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

            canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', height);

            if (canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d')) {

                canvg(canvas, svg);

                return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

            }
            else {
                alert("Your browser doesn't support this feature, please use a modern browser");
                return false;
            }

        }
    }(Highcharts));
```

And after that use jsPDF to render PDF in frontend. Use canvas context as image and place that object on the pdf using jsPDF library.The method name is *addImage* .

```
var pdfOptions = {
            orientation: "landscape", // One of "portrait" or "landscape" (or shortcuts "p" (Default), "l")
            unit: "mm",              //Measurement unit to be used when coordinates are specified. One of "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
            format: "a4"             //One of 'a3', 'a4' (Default),'a5' ,'letter' ,'legal'
        }
        var *doc* = new jsPDF(pdfOptions);
```

Create jsPDF object

```
doc.addPage();
var imageData = $(this).highcharts().createCanvas();
doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', left, top, charWidth, chartHeight);
```

add image to *doc* object, that imageData derived from the canvas element that retured from above ***createCanvas*** function.

```
doc.save('example.pdf');
```

After that save pdf.

In this case frontend highchart pdf generation was success, but chart resolution is very low.
*Is there any posibility to improve resolution on charts in rendered pdf.?*

Comment: Couldn't you just use standard Highcharts exporting module for exporting your charts to pdf? Here you can find some more information about this module http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: Yes I also go through this link.but In that case unable to increase resolution on created canvas element.

Comment: I am wondering if it is not possible to use sourceWidth and sourceHeight in your exporting. Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3x3qrzm5/